# Convert Func<xxx, yyy> to static method?

Tags: c#, .net, expression

Given the method:

```
void SomeMethod<TIn, TOut>(Func<TIn, TOut> fn)
{
}

SomeMethod<int, int>(x => { return x * 2 });
```

Is it possible to convert fn to a static MethodInfo somehow? In .net 4.5 / Roslyn, Microsoft changed lambdas to be instances only. STUPID.

That makes it difficult to later generically do fn.Method.Invoke()..

The braces throw a monkey wrench into the works as they prevent the expression from converting to a `Expression<Func<int, int>>` which can compile to a static.

Comment: This really sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you trying to do that having a static methodinfo would be the solution?

Comment: I'm quite unclear about what you actually mean. However, I don't see the difficulty you're having invoking it. You can write this: `fn.Method.Invoke(fn.Target, new object[] { 1 });` which is no more difficult than previously `fn.Method.Invoke(null, new object[] { 1 });`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, yes, I want a static methodinfo so I can call via emitIL. I can call the instance one of course, its just going to be a pain due to the IL.

Comment: @Rob, I will be using the methodInfo via IL, so that makes it a pain to store and get the target on the stack in the right order.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Well, it wouldn't make sense in a case like this for it to be static: `var a = 3; SomeMethod<int, int>(x => { return x * 2 + a; });` because it has knowledge about a captured variable. A `Func<TIn, TOut>` is not necessarily a static method, nor should you assume that it is. Bite the bullet and invoke it on the instance. If you're hand-writing IL, you should be willing to accept the fact that *everything* you do is going to be verbose.

Comment: Why can't you simply change the parameter to be `SomeMethod<TIn, TOut>(Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> fn)`? Also, what would `SomeMethod` not return the result of the `fn`?

Comment: @DavidPine -- doesn't compile if you have a body :) (braces).

Comment: Right, that is my point -- you cannot convert a lambda expression to an expression tree. This will enforce the consumer to use `SomeMethod` as you desire.